# How to write the test method for the following code?

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, apex-code

I have code for this before update trigger and I have to write the test method for it. I am completely new to apex and this is the first trigger I wrote but not getting how to write test method for it.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c0gg.jpg)

Comment: Yes, I know... Lets post a picture of the code instead of including it in the question. Great idea.. [mcve] [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot doesn't provide much of the details, but I am writing the test class based on the info you have shared.

Tweak the code based on how you have implemented the trigger.

```
@isTest
private class StatusCloseDateTest {
    @isTest static void testStatusCloseDate() {
        yourObjAPIName__c rectoupdate = new yourObjAPIName__c();
        rectoupdate.name = 'testValue';
        
        /* based on the type of trigger (insert,update,delete) you wrote
           perform the dml action. 
           EG:insert rectoupdate/update rectoupdate/delete rectoupdate
        */
        
        insert rectoupdate; 
        /* when you perform this dml operation, the trigger will get 
           invoked and the code you have written in the trigger will 
           be covered by this test class method.
        */

    }
}
```

Run the test methods in this class.

- In the Developer Console, click Test | New Run.
- Under Test Classes, click "StatusCloseDateTest".
- To add all the test methods in the "StatusCloseDateTest" class to the test run, click Add Selected.
- Click Run.

For more details refer : [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro)